# Makefile: two different executables taking two overlapping subsets of code

Tags: c, makefile

This is my situation, I am trying to write a Makefile for my c program, it has these components --

- 2 Headers:

  1. `src/header1.h`
  2. `src/header2.h`
- `N` Sources:

  1. `src/src1.c`
  2. `src/src2.c`
  3. `src/src3.c` ...
  4. `src/srcn.c`
- 2 Mains:

  1. `src/main1.c`
  2. `src/main2.c`

`main1.c` and `main2.c` takes all the same `src*.c` and `header*.h` files, but in a different way. It would be really nice if I could write my Makefile in this way --

```
CC          := gcc
INCLUDES    := $(wildcard src/*.h)
SRC1        := all src*.c sources and main1.c (not main2.c)
SRC2        := all src*.c sources and main2.c (not main1.c)
IFLAGS      := $(addprefix -I/,$(INCLUDES))
CFLAGS      := -g -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 $(IFLAGS)
LDFLAGS     := -lm 
OBJS1       := all objects from src*.c (i.e. src*.o) and main1.o
OBJS1       := all objects from src*.c (i.e. src*.o) and main2.o   
APP1        := app1
APP2        := app2

all: $(APP1) $(APP2)

$(APP1): $(OBJS1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(APP2): $(OBJS2)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJS1): $(SRC1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJS2): $(SRC2)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm $(OBJS1) 
    rm $(OBJS2) 
    rm $(APP1)
    rm $(APP2)
```

How do I write the target/prerequisites rule for `$SRC1`, `$SRC2`, `$OBJS1` and `$OBJS2` above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COMMON = \
    src1.c \
    src2.c \
    ... \
    srcn.c

MAIN1 = main1.c
MAIN2 = main2.c
COMOBJ = ${COMMON:.c=.o}
OBJS1 = ${MAIN1:.c=.o} ${COMOBJ}
OBJS2 = ${MAIN2:.c=.o} ${COMOBJ}
```

I often write macros such as `MAIN1.c = main1.c` as POSIX requires `make` to support that notation (and all the variants I've encountered *do* support it).  But beware the `vim` doesn't think the macro names like that are kosher (which is a bug in `vim`'s recognition of `make` macros).  Then I'd write:

```
COMMON.c = ...
MAIN1.c  = main1.c
...

FILES1.o = ${MAIN1.c:.c=.o} ${COMMON.c:.c=.o}
```

etc.  Not everyone likes this notation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with just a list of objects

```
OBJS = src1.o src2.o #... etc

main1: main1.o $(OBJS)

main2: main2.o $(OBJS)
```

and let make use your provided `CC`, `CFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS` to figure out the rest